Problematic annotation for instances of a class that extends Array
For example, in TypeScript you can specify that the elements of an array must be numbers (const array: number[] = [];). However, I'm unable to specify that the elements of a subclass of Array must be numbers, strings, or any other type.
The code snippet below creates a List class that extends Array. TypeScript throws an error because of the last 3 lines where I specify the type of elements that the instances of List must include. Does anyone how to correctly annotate that? Please note that I wouldn't want to add an annotation to where the class List is declared. This is because I'd like instances of List to be flexible.
class List extends Array {
    shuffle() {}
}

const listA: number[] = new List();
listA.shuffle();

const listD: boolean<List> = new List();
const listB: number<List> = new List();
const listC: string<List> = new List();


Did you mean List<boolean>, in the same way that it's Array<boolean> (equivalent to boolean[])? Currently your List isn't generic.

Thank you for your response! I've had a look at the response from user Unmitigated and it works. :D

T[] is equivalent to Array<T>, so you can make your List class generic and extend Array on the same generic type.
class List<T> extends Array<T> {
    shuffle() {}
}

const listA: List<number> = new List();
listA.shuffle();

// alternatively:
const listB = new List<boolean>();

